# Ways of deploying mind reading technology

Tags: nanotechnology, mind-control, mind

Previous version of [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/216490/applications-and-implications-of-mind-reading-technology) which is closed because of being too broad.

In a dystopian world setting, mind-reading technology is possible (say, with nano-robots or super-chips), but it is secretly owned only by some specific group(s): for example, country government(s), people with high power, some secret agents, high/big-tech societies/companies, or similar organisations. They own this power and technology secretly and don’t want to make it known to public, let alone available to people outside their organisation.

Provided such technology existed, what would be their way of deploying them (and used upon whom)?

Comment: We'd need to know the specifics of the mind control technology to be able to make meaningful statements about how such a technology could be deployed.

Comment: How they deploy it would largely depend on their objectives and the context and situational aspects. Could you give many more details of what your world's about so we can judge the specifics.

Comment: Why haven't you edited the closed question instead of reposting it?

Comment: I've gotta VTC:Needs Details. What is the specific problem you're trying to resolve? Remember that questions about the actions and decisions of characters are off-topic, so you must be asking about, what, how the mind-reading process works? How the target brain might react to the invasion? To reiterate, questions like "what valuable info could be obtained?" are off-topic because that's too story-based. What world rule or system are you asking about?

Answer (score 3):

The mind-reading technology has to be able to decode a mind-state (remotely, to boot) and make it available locally, interfering with the normal process of the bearer's own mind; otherwise, it simply couldn't work.

The same technology can therefore perform a very limited reading of the bearer's mind, and translate any concept of "violating the secret of mind reading" with an increasing amount of unease and discomfort, up to and including a focal seizure... or a lethal ischemic attack.

Answer (score 2):

**It is used for the pettiest of reasons.**

A small group within a political party owns this tech.  They use it to spy on their political rivals in their own party.  They initially hope to uncover dirty secrets like affairs or demon worship or weird fetishes but they get none of that.  They resort to mind reading to learn what sorts of things irritate their rivals (toilet paper hung the wrong way, squeaky desk chair wheel, bird poop on hood of car (the bulky kind)) and then making sure those things happen to their rivals.

These activities do not make their rivals less effective.  It does bring the mind readers great joy and long periods of cackling with glee.